# ZF Datagrid Edit Form Validation failed cause of Ignored element

Tags: php, zend-framework, zfdatagrid

I have edit form for entity. There is element

```
          $feedback = new FeedbackViewer('Feedback');
    $feedback->setLabel('Feedback')->setRequired(false);
    $feedback->setPostId($this->testimonialId);
    $feedback->setAppId($this->config->testimonials->appId);
    $feedback->setIgnore(true);
    $this->addElement($feedback);
```

This feedback viewer loads iframe with another zf datagrid that shows feedbacks inside the form.
I use this form in ZF datagrid

```
$entityId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('edit');
        if ($entityId) {
            $entityForm = call_user_func($formCallback, $entityId);
            $form->setUsePreDefinedFormElements(true);
            $form->setForm($entityForm);
        }
```

But ZF datagrid after saving action triggers error Validation failed. Removing the feedbacks element makes it saving correctly.
any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $grid->setForm($form);
                if($action != 'show') {
                $form->getForm()->getElement('form_reset')->setLabel(null);
                $form->getForm()->getElement('form_submit')->setLabel(null);

                $gridParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('grid');
                $startParam = $this->getRequest()->getParam('start');


                if ($gridParam) {
                        if ($gridParam == 'all') {
                                $gridParam = 'index';
                        }

                        // Attach to event listener custom redirect action
                        $grid->listenEvent('crud.after_update', array($this, 'setGridRedirectCallback'), array('action' => $gridParam, 'page' => $startParam));
                        $grid->listenEvent('crud.after_delete', array($this, 'setGridRedirectCallback'), array('action' => $gridParam));
                        $form->getForm()->getElement('form_reset')->setAttribs(array('onclick' => 'window.location.href = "/admin/' . $gridParam . (($startParam) ? '/start/' . $startParam : '') . '";'));
                }
```

I solved this issue with putting this in If tags, couldn't find better solution.